# CurrentPageReference in Aura Lightning Application?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

Is there a way to get CurrentPageReference in Aura onePage app ?

I want to use it for LWC event passing.

[image: Method to use:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_add_params_url) Salesforce documentation

Comment: thanks, does this url (one-page app, aura application) supports page references? https://my.lightning.force.com/c/TripRequestor.app. It still can't read currentPageReference: "Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"